# Скрипт обратного отсчета в числовом формате (не время)

Tags: javascript

Не могу найти обратный счетчик в числовом формате, а не в формате времени.
Мне нужно что бы скрипт, каждые 5 секунд отнимал от стартового числа 14 и останавливался при приближении к 0, то есть что бы в минус не заходило.
Везде только обратные счетчики по времени...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, можно так:

```js
let counter = 141;

const timer = setInterval(() => {
  if (counter < 14) return clearInterval(timer);

  counter -= 14;
  console.log(counter);
}, 5000);
```